# Android View not attached to window manager (dialog dismiss)

Tags: android

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41c2e378 V.E..... R......D 0,0-450,161} not attached to window manager

**MainActivity:**

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 new SetEntrySent(SecondActivity.class, false).execute(id);

 Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class,);
                           startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
```

**CreateEntry Async**
**onpostexecute**

```
 dialog.dismiss();
}//finishing class
```

**MainActivity:**

```
 **onresume**

//checks again and if entry not sent, it also calls:
   new SetEntrySent(SecondActivity.class, false).execute(id);
```

for

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

it gives errors.

> Process: com.example..androidwithlogin, PID: 27426
>                                                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41c2e378
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-450,161} not attached to window manager

First, main activity calls second activity. Second activity, after operations call asynctask and at same time finishes and intents to mainactivity.

When i do without `finish()` it works.

i can intent mainactivity from asynctask, but how secondactivity will finish? asynctask has context of secondactivity. Can it finish it?

i searched and found this

```
   private void dismissProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and it works for this.

But because of async, asynctask is called a lot of times.

What is the best way to prevent this? If i put going to mainactivity to postexecute of async

**CreateEntry Async**
**onpostexecute**

```
 dialog.dismiss();
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class,);
                           startActivity(intent);
                            finish();   
}//finishing class
```

can it finish secondactivity also and is that safe? because asynctask will be finishing, mainactivity can not call again it.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check isFinishing function on activity. Something like

```
if ( !YourActivity.isFinishing() && dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) 
    dialog.dismiss();
```